# Why Retrofit can't resolve No connection - Check internet connection on Android?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, networking, retrofit

Hello guys I have one specific problem. I'm using retrofit library for all of my network calls. And I have one method to send points to another user and if any error occurs, the server will return me code 400 and string alongside it that I will have to show to user. This thing is working I created it like this ( NetworkSDK is sending a body with params and expect to recieve an error status string if it occurs) so logically I am processing my errors in `onResponse` method (if Networksdk recieve an object with error string) and if `onFailure` occurs there is no error. But now I have a bigger problem. If there is no connection at all, if user turns off internet in that fragment it will again go to `onFailure` and show message that points are sent. Ordinary I would do that via status code if status code is 200 than it's okey but for some reasons I can't get any status code via response.code() command. Here is the code :

```
  @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        try {
            final String cardNo;
            String amountstring = bodovi.getText().toString();
            final Integer amount = Integer.valueOf(amountstring);
            cardNo = brojkartice.getText().toString();
            Log.d("Broj bodova:", amount.toString());
            Log.d("Broj kartice:", cardNo);
            final SendPoints Posiljka = new SendPoints();
            Posiljka.setAmount(amount);
            Posiljka.setCardNumber(cardNo);
                NetworkSDK.getInstance().SendPoints(Posiljka, new Callback<SendPointsResponse>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call<SendPointsResponse> call, Response<SendPointsResponse> response) {

                        Log.d("Response code:", "" + response.code());
                        Log.d("Kartica", Posiljka.getCardNumber());
                        Log.d("Broj bodova", Posiljka.getAmount().toString());


                        try {
                            SendPointsResponse error = (new Gson()).fromJson(response.errorBody().string(), SendPointsResponse.class);

                            if (error.getCode().equals("-1"))
                                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Neuspješno slanje bodoava. Neispravni ulazni podaci.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            if (error.getCode().equals("-2"))
                                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Neuspješno slanje bodova. Korisnički podaci nisu popunjeni.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            if (error.getCode().equals("-3"))
                                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Neuspješno slanje bodova. Korisnik ima rezervisanu nagradu.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            if (error.getCode().equals("-4"))
                                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Neuspješno slanje bodova. U toku jednog mjeseca bodove je moguće poslati maksimalno dva puta.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            if (error.getCode().equals("-5"))
                                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Neuspješno slanje bodova. Bodove nije moguće poslati samom sebi.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            if (error.getCode().equals("-6"))
                                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Neuspješno slanje bodova. Korisnik ne može primiti bodove.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            if (error.getCode().equals("-100"))
                                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Neuspješno slanje bodova. Greška nepoznata.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }


                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Call<SendPointsResponse> call, Throwable t) {

                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Uspješno slanje bodova.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });



        }catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Podaci nisu ispravni, provjerite podatke !", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }   }

});


}
```

I basicly need some idea in OnFailure method to detect if user is turned off internet and to display proper message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4238921/detect-whether-there-is-an-internet-connection-available-on-android) where is explained in detail if internet connection status is available usgin the `ConnectivityManager` through the Connectivity Service.

Notice that your app will need permissions for obtaining the network status:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Comment: It's good now I did network checker function but I forgot to include permission

Comment: Great! I pointed explicity that because is something we use to forget ;)